Custom PMD Rule - alternative to deprecated getNode
Hello awesome community.
Problem: getNode is deprecated.
I'm creating a new PMD rule and I found a solution to my use case, but the approach is leveraging a getNode method from the AbstractApexNode class.
The problem is that this method is annotated as @Deprecated and @InternalApi and I could not even find it in the latest PMD releases, probably already removed.
Because I want to have the rule compatible with latest PMD releases, I'm looking for alternatives.
Rule Definition
When using a logger via Logger.getLogger, the argument should match the class name.
Example Error
public class MyClass {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DifferentClass.class);
    // ERROR: MyClass != DifferentClass
}

Example Success
public class MyClass {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class);
    // OK: MyClass == MyClass
}

Suboptimal solution using deprecated getNode

I'm able to get the class name using getImage() on the ASTUserClass.
I'm able to match the method call (ASTMethodCallExpression) for Logger.getLogger.
I'm UNABLE to get the DifferentClass.class/MyClass.class without the getNode method. In my example below, I have ASTClassRefExpression which doesn't provide the type of the class. I can access ClassRefExpression which provides the desired type, but only via deprecated getNode method, which I'd prefer to avoid using.

@Override
public Object visit(ASTClassRefExpression node, Object data) {
   ClassRefExpression ref = node.getNode();
   System.out.println(ref);
   // DifferentClass.class
   return super.visit(node, data);
}

I also tried accessing parameters via ASTMethodCallExpression, but that provides only the number of input parameters and not the actual input parameters.
Question
How to get the DifferentClass.class/MyClass.class without the getNode method?

Can you try this? ClassRefExpression ref = (ClassRefExpression) node;

I can't do that. "Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.apex.ast.ASTUserClass' to 'apex.jorje.semantic.ast.expression.ClassRefExpression'" because ASTClassRefExpression extends AbstractApexNode
